# WooCommerce how to disable redirection to My Account page

Tags: wordpress, authentication, redirect, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We've a WoordPress with WooCommerce (which we are not using at the moment, but don't want to get rid of), and when users sign up and follow the set up password instructions, they end up in `oursite.com/wp-login.php`.

> **The problem comes when they log in, because they're automatically redirected to WooComerce's My Account page. We would like to take users to a different page.**

Is it possible to disable this WooCommerce functionality? Choose a different page or even go to the homepage instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

WooCommerce uses this filter to force redirect customers to my-account page `woocommerce_prevent_admin_access`, so you need to pass false to this filter to disable the woocommerce redirect

```
add_action(
    'admin_init',
    function() {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_admin_access', '__return_false', 100 );
    },
    1
);
```

You can then use `login_redirect` filter after that to customize the wordpress redirect link after login

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce has two hooks for redirect after registration and login:

```
<?php
/**
 * Redirect to shop after login.
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'ywp_login_redirect', 1100, 2 );
function ywp_login_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['redirect_to'] ) ) {
        $redirect = esc_url( $_GET['redirect_to'] );
    } else {
        $redirect = home_url();
    }

    return $redirect;
}

/**
 * Redirect after registration.
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'ywp_register_redirect' );
function ywp_register_redirect( $redirect ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['redirect_to'] ) ) {
        $redirect = esc_url( $_GET['redirect_to'] );
    } else {
        $redirect = home_url();
    }

    return $redirect;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This code is also used to change the `wp-admin/wp-login.php` redirect:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'ywp_redirect_wp_login' );
function ywp_redirect_wp_login() {
        if ( isset( $_GET['redirect_to'] ) ) {
            $redirect = esc_url( $_GET['redirect_to'] );
        } else {
            $redirect = home_url();
        }
    
        return $redirect;
}
```

Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active theme/child theme. Tesed and works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, althought it's not the desired output. These hooks work when you're using WooCommerce login. For exemple, when you are in `yoursite.com/my-account`, but not from `yoursite.com/wp-login.php`.

Comment: I updated the code, now the default wordpress login will be redirected to the desired address ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use this to redirect a user to the home page:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'custom_login', 10, 3 );

function custom_login( ){
    global $wp_query;
    if (is_account_page()) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
        exit();
    };
};
```

Comment: Not working :( Thank you though. It does nothing, I don't know about php nor WP development, but the error could be in that `if`. I want a redirection once the user logs in though, not sure if it's clear.

Comment: I see, well i've tested it on my woocommerce website and it works fine!!! After a user logs in, s/he would be redirected to his/her account page, so that if condition is checking whether they've logged in or not, if they have, then they will be redirected to the home page! Would it be possible to provide me with the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, although I still don't understand the "architecture" of it...

**Why do I have to force the redirection using an extra hook in my functions file, instead of disabling WooCommerce's behaviour?**

Anyway :)

```
/**
 * Redirect user after successful login.
 *
 * @param string $redirect_to URL to redirect to.
 * @param string $request URL the user is coming from.
 * @param object $user Logged user's data.
 * @return string
 */
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
            //check for admins
            if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
                    // redirect them to the default place
                    return $redirect_to;
            } else {
                    //return home_url();
                    $redirect = get_page_link( 25159 );
                    return $redirect;
            }
    } else {
            return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```